# Spring Transaction over multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I would like to know if there is possibility to have transaction over multiple threads.
The problem is, I need to persist large number of records. If i do it sequentially it's going to take long time. That's why i need to partition these entity objects and persist them parallelly. Which is faster and works great. But only trade off is. Each thread is in it's own transaction. If any of this fail. It will rollback its own thread transaction but not all of them.
Is there any way to run all the threads in single transaction. So that i can control the transaction.
I am using JpaRepository respository to persist or delete.

code sample

```
@Transactional
public boolean executeTransaction(final EntityWrapper entityWrapper) {
       transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManagerRepo);
try {
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                repo.saveAll(list); // Saves all at once. Batch commit. Which takes long time

         //      other way executing in ThreadPoolExecutor saving 200 records parallelly 
            entitiesList = partition(entitiesMasterList, 200);
            executor = ThreadPoolExecutor.initializeThreadPoolExecutor(entitiesList.size());
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Consider storing the changes in a staging table so that each group of records can be handled within its own thread/transaction.  If any of those stage updates fail, then only that group of records needs to be corrected.  When all staged records are ready, then merge to the actual table in a single transaction.  There may be problems if the target table is updated while the changes are being staged, or the DB could run out of undo space when the final merge is executed.

Comment: That, or the other way around: backup the table before the batch, operate on the real table, and restore from backup once you know something went wrong. It depends on whether you're 'optimistic' or 'pessimistic' about the batch process going awry

Comment: I am not sure if i am allowed to do that. Considering our environment. Also in some cases i need to delete and insert rows. In that case staging tables might not work for me.

Comment: Consider using batch inserts, they are fast enough not to need multiple threads.